# Problem with jquery button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem in the jquery click event.

My web page involves creating a button through javascript and assigning a class to the button ( call it A ). Now I want to detect the click of that button and I have written the following code for it :

```
 $(".A").click( function () {

    // do something

 });
```

To my surprise, this click event never gets called.

But when I make the button statically on the webpage ( during design time ), the same code works.

Is there a different approach to bind a button click with jquery in case a button is created dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [$.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$(".A").live('click', function () {

   // do something

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `live()` jquery method to automatically wire up events to new elements. Or, as you create the new button, attach the new click event.

```
var newbutton = $('<input type="button" value="click me"/>');
somediv.append(newbutton);
newbutton.click(yourhandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler fires at page load, before your button exists.

Either reset the event handler after you create the button, or use `.live` for late-binding:

```
$(".A").live('click', function () {
   // do something
});
```

Now the handler will apply to `.A` even created in the future.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use the [live-function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) of jquery! In difference to the click-function, it watches for dom manipulations. as you can imagine its slightly slower than the .click().

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```

Felix

Comment: You mean, the function that you didn't use in your code example?!?

Comment: Yes this is the bind method You should have copied this example from the docs 
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});

Comment: It's "slightly slower"? Slightly slower at what? They do different jobs. If you compare how fast this method is at doing X and how fast the other method is at doing X, the result is "infinite" because the other method _cannot_ do X.